# How to use the installed (pre-compiled) drake as external with bazel?

Tags: drake

I am working on a C++ project with drake, using bazel as the build system. Previously, I use the drake source code as the external, following the [drake_bazel_external](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake-external-examples/tree/main/drake_bazel_external) example. Everything works fine.

Since I want to use the SNOPT solver in drake, I want to change to use the pre-compiled drake. I follow the [drake_bazel_installed](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake-external-examples/tree/main/drake_bazel_installed) example. However, I got the following errors.

```
Compiling kuka/diffIK_controller.cc failed: (Exit 1): gcc failed: error executing command /usr/bin/gcc -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -O2 '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' -DNDEBUG -ffunction-sections ... (remaining 27 arguments skipped)

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/drake/_virtual_includes/.drake_headers/drake/common/default_scalars.h:3,
                 from bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/drake/_virtual_includes/.drake_headers/drake/systems/framework/leaf_system.h:14,
                 from ./kuka/diffIK_controller.h:3,
                 from kuka/diffIK_controller.cc:3:
bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/drake/_virtual_includes/.drake_headers/drake/common/autodiff.h:12:10: fatal error: Eigen/Core: No such file or directory
   12 | #include <Eigen/Core>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I also find that the `apps` in the `drake_bazel_external` cannot be compiled successfully by `drake_bazel_installed` setting. The error message is

```
ERROR: error loading package 'app': Label '@drake//tools/skylark:py.bzl' is invalid because 'tools/skylark' is not a package; perhaps you meant to put the colon here: '@drake//:tools/skylark/py.bzl'?
```

---

Update 
The bug can be produced by both the `http_archive` fetched drake and the `apt` installed drake (the latest stable drake I think, since I just installed it yesterday). I have isolated the relevant code to reproduce the bug in a github [repo](https://github.com/CWEzio/reproduce_drake_bazel_installed). Currently, I can get the original apps in `drake_bazel_installed` to work.

---

Update 
By adding

```
# solve the eigen not found bug
build --cxxopt=-I/usr/include/eigen3
```

to the `.bazelrc` file, I can solve the above problem. However, when I try to build a program that uses `iiwa_status_receiver.h`, I encounter a new problem.

```
ERROR: /home/chenwang/repro_drake_bazel_external/drake_bazel_installed/apps/BUILD.bazel:102:10: Compiling apps/connection_test.cc failed: (Exit 1): gcc failed: error executing command /usr/bin/gcc -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -O2 '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' -DNDEBUG -ffunction-sections ... (remaining 32 arguments skipped)

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox and retain the sandbox build root for debugging
In file included from apps/connection_test.cc:10:
bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/drake/_virtual_includes/.drake_headers/drake/manipulation/kuka_iiwa/iiwa_status_receiver.h:6:10: fatal error: drake/lcmt_iiwa_status.hpp: No such file or directory
    6 | #include "drake/lcmt_iiwa_status.hpp"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
INFO: Elapsed time: 2.967s, Critical Path: 0.24s
INFO: 2 processes: 2 internal.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

This problem is also a missing header file problem. I have update the github [repo](https://github.com/CWEzio/reproduce_drake_bazel_installed) to reproduce this problem.

Comment: Could you update your question with the exact steps for how to reproduce the problem?  Trying to get [drake-external-examples/drake_bazel_installed/apps](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake-external-examples/tree/main/drake_bazel_installed/apps) to work is probably the next step.  What version of that repo are you using, what which  Drake binary did you download or install, what environment variable(s) did you set, and what command-line bazel command are you running?

Comment: @jwnimmer-tri Thank you for your reply! I have isolated the relevant code in this github [repo](https://github.com/CWEzio/reproduce_drake_bazel_installed). Could you please have a look? I can successfully build and run the original apps in drake_bazel_installed but the bugs happen when I try to build more complex program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Drake (filed as https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/17965 now).

To work around it, pass `--cxxopt=-I/usr/include/eigen3` on all of your `bazel` commands, e.g., by adding this line to your projects' `.bazelrc` file:

```
build --cxxopt=-I/usr/include/eigen3
```

Edit: The [nightly builds](https://drake.mit.edu/apt.html#nightly-releases) of Apt packages as of 20220923 should have this fixed as well.

Comment: Thank you. By passing `--cxxopt=-I/usr/include/eigen3` I can solve the missing eigen header problem. However, when I try to use the `iiwa_status_receiver.h` to build a new program, I get a new header missing problem. I have update the git repo to reproduce this new problem. Could you please have a look again?

Comment: The big picture is that `drake_bazel_installed` was an awkward experiment that has never been well-loved, and has a lot of rough edges like this.  I'll try to fix the `lcm` include problems (and, after that they will be `unsupported/Eigen` problems) but you might be better off going a different route until `drake_bazel_installed` matures a bit.

Comment: See https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/18008 for the fix.

Comment: Thanks! I am currently using cmake as the alternative option and it works fine.